# External USB HD not being automounted according to fstab

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab, external-hdd, automount

I have an external USB HD and I want it to be mounted on `/data/FS/WD2Tb/`.

I added the following line to my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
UUID="a05fab8c-5c4c-42be-9898-830ec5ad45dc" /data/FS/WD2Tb/ ext4 defaults,nofail,nobootwait 0 2
```

Yet, it's being mounted on `/media/my_user/WD2Tb`.

The UUID is correctly according to blkid:

```
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="WD2Tb" UUID="a05fab8c-5c4c-42be-9898-830ec5ad45dc" TYPE="ext4"
```

Do you have any idea why it's being automounted on `/media/my_user/WD2Tb` instead `/data/FS/WD2Tb/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the quotation marks. I didn't notice it before and it makes the fstab line to be ignored.